# RESTful HTTP GET to upload a CSV file as input and wait for return format in JSON/XML

Tags: rest, file-upload, http-get

Is it possible to use HTTP GET to upload a file, and wait the server for its return in JSON format?

To be specific, I am planning to upload a CSV file containing information via HTTP GET. Now once uploaded, backend modules will process the information in the CSV file and server will send a JSON-formatted return to the user.

Comment: I think you mean POST, not GET, right?

Comment: If you mean uploading by POST, then yes it is possible.
What language are you coding at?

Comment: thanks for your comments. But I already know uploading via POST. What I am asking is if it's possible/feasible to upload using GET, regardless of the language i'll be using